# IIS HTTP Error 503 after in place upgrade from 2008 R2 to 2012 R2

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I recently upgraded one of our application servers from Server 2008 R2 to Server 2012 R2. Everything seems to be working fine except for our little Intranet. When trying to get to it, you are immediately greeted with `Error 503 Service is unavailable`.
I did some troubleshooting but nothing has seemed to helped. I made sure the app pool associated with the website is running and double checked the identity. (It's using ApplicaionPoolIdentity). What else can I try? Thanks all!

Comment: As far as I know, there are multiple reason about 503 error. Could you please check the event viewer for more info? After you find out the details error message, I suggest you could refer to this article to know how to solve it. Article:https://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/12/HTTP-Error-503-The-service-is-unavailable.html

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the the application pool that our intranet runs from was set to use .NET CLR Version 1.1 instead of version 2.0. After switching to version 2.0 and recycling/refreshing the site, the intranet came right up. Thanks all!